# is better long and repeated msgs with .volatile flag or shorter but 'un-missable'?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I want to make an app that relies in socket.io to offer real-time collaborative editing and I wonder which of these cases is better/faster:

```
<textarea id="some-id" onkeypress="broadcast()" ... >Type your text here</textarea>
```

- every time a change is made the client broadcasts the whole input with the volatile flag, so if a message is lost, the next one will replace it.
- every time a change is made the client broadcasts ***only that change*** and other clients apply it.

Also, are there any other APIs/frameworks/plugins that I can use rather than socket-io for collaborative document editing?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me answer your question a year after you posted this, because you're probably very impatient by now!

I think you would be better of with sending the change only.

- If two persons are typing at the same time, you will lose data if you're overwriting everything, even with *very* low latency. That is unacceptable.
- Without the volatile flag, the latency will be already very low, like a fraction of a second. (Also depends on the user's connection, of course). Remote persons will probably not notice these tiny delays.
- Documents may get large, so if someone is happily typing away in a big document, you're sending a lot of data around, which is not efficient.

---

Socket.IO is pretty good for this job: It has great cross-browser compatibility and the overhead is  acceptable. If you're only targeting browsers that support HTML5's Websocket, you could use a [Websocket package](https://npmjs.org/package/websocket) for node.js.